# Orchestrating Talend Jobs/ Tasks with Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, talend, azure-data-factory

is it posssible to orchestrate Talend Jobs  with Azure Data factory? On the talend website, there is an API called Metaservlet. Has any one used it with Data factory API to orchestrate/ trigger Talend Jobs?

Answer (score 0):

If you can make RESTful calls via Azure Data Factory, you should be able to use the Metaservlet API (which isn't actually RESTful, but uses a more RPC style).

However, in my experience the Metaservlet API isn't very secure (or implemented well for that matter) as you have to send your JSON payload via a Base64 encoded URL query parameter. Most of the time, you'll be sending a username and password within that Base64 encoded string. This is pretty much like sending the username and password in cleartext - which isn't the sort of thing you should be doing anywhere, let alone over the Internet.

As an alternative, you could implement your own more secure REST wrapper as a proxy for the Metaservlet API.

Comment: How do you implement a secure REST wrapper?

Comment: You could use Talend ESB Routes (not jobs) to create a REST service with Apache Camel. As for deployment, you have options: deploy it in the same Tomcat container that TAC is using (metaservlet API is also in this container) or you can use Talend Runtime, which is based on Apache Karaf. Either way, you should be calling the metaservlet locally in the REST implementation so that you don't leak your passwords via URL. Tomcat or Runtime will manage HTTPS and certificates, so you don't need to implement that yourself if you use Talend Routes. Check out the Talend help website.

Comment: This link should help you out: https://help.talend.com/reader/eZlGM25B48v7aoSuC92FqQ/IVd5gndDACbq3fAi8helGA